# Does "either or " means XOR or OR?

Tags: combinatorics, logic, recurrence-relations, propositional-calculus

A set of r marbles is selected from an infinite supply of red, blue, white and yellow marbles. A selection must satisfy the condition that either the number of red marbles is even and the number of blue marbles is odd, or the number of white marbles is even and the number of yellow marbles is odd.
Does it mean a selection is invalid when both red is even and blue is odd as well as white is even and yellow is odd ? Do we discard this case while counting the number of selection ?

Comment: "either/or, but not both" means XOR. So "either/or" means OR.

Comment: So this is same as OR ? Grammatically it says any one out of the 2 but not both so I am confused

Comment: The description in your question is OR (and the answer to the bottom line question is no).

Comment: What will this statement mean " Given a bag of marbles of 4 colours, select 4 marbles so that either 2 are red or 2 are white " ? Does it mean we will include the case when 2 are red and rest 2 are white ? I just wanted to clear the doubt about "either or " meaning when on satisfying conditions

Comment: I think that the question is about the use of English simple "or" as opposed to "either ... or ...", i.e. whether there is a difference between (normally inclusive) "or" and (possibly exclusive) "either ... or". If this is what the question is about, it might be better addressed at the [English language and usage SE](http://english.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @lemontree: Certainly this question is a fit on EL&U if it was about ordinary English usage. In this case, however, it is probably about English as used in Mathematics, which has numerous peculiarities. For instance, a lot of authors define mathematical properties by "We say that X is P **if** Q holds" when actually the precise definition should use "**iff**" (if and only if). I personally use "iff" but it pays for students to be aware of the discrepancies between English and 'Mathematical English'. =)

Answer (score 6):

According to *Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary* (CALD), it states that "**either-or describes a situation in which there is a choice between two different plans of action, but both together are not possible**".

For example, it's an either-or situation - we can buy a new car this year or we can go on holiday, but we can't do both.

Therefore, **either-or is XOR**.

BTW, in logic, "or" is often used to describe **inclusive or**, but in nature language, we also use it to describe exclusive-or situation. For example, "Would you like coffee or tea?" means either of them, but not both.

Comment: There are native American logicians, who are using either-or in the meaning of inclusive or. R. Smullyan is using this phrase as informal expression of disjunction in the book "What is the Name of This Book?" consequently.

Answer (score 2):

In mathematical writing, "P or Q." always means "At least one of P,Q is true.", and indeed is the same as "$P \lor Q$" not "$P \oplus Q$" (P XOR Q). Actually, it can be argued that the English "or" is also inclusive **when used as** a boolean connective. I'm a native speaker and I have never seen any factual assertion "P or Q" in English where it is incorrect to interpret it as inclusive. (In "Do you want tea or coffee?" the "or" is not used as a boolean connective.)

Comment: That the normal use of "or" should be inclusive is clear, but as I understood it, the qustion is about "either... or". I think that this behaves a lot differently - to me (as a non-native speaker), it seems that "either... or" indeed is closer to a boolean XOR.

Comment: @lemontree: Well. All you need is to show me a counter-example. =) Do you have one? In all my life I have never seen an instance of "either A or B" to be non-inclusive, which is why to be precise everyone has to say "but not both" if they want XOR.

Comment: As I said, I'm not a native speaker, but if I were to say "You can have tea or coffee", I would not be upset if my guest wanted both, but if I say "You can either have a bike or an i-phone for your birthday", the child should better decide for one of them ;)

Comment: @lemontree: My very answer mentions that and states that "or" is not a boolean connective in "tea or coffee". In your second example, it should be "can have either a bike or an i-phone", and actually does not violate the inclusive or meaning: "It is permissible that you have at least a bike or an i-phone." (which does not **promise** that you can have both). It is further implied by the context that you can choose at least one, but arguably that is beyond the surface meaning.

Comment: Okay then, I trust you on the native speaker intuition part, and a discussion of context influence (I originally come from the field of linguistics where the pragmatic division between inclusive and exclusive or has been a longtime discussion) would be out of the scope of this question because of what you said in your comment above (matehmatical as opposed to everyday usage).

Comment: @lemontree: I'd be interested to hear a bit of your linguistics viewpoint over at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44058/logic. I concluded that "or" has multiple meanings in English, and the factual "or" is always inclusive, but I haven't given much thought to the other meanings of "or".

Comment: I have written some lines in the chat.